# Create custom email accounts with Heroku

Tags: email, heroku

I have a client hosted with Godaddy and I am willing to change to Heroku.

I have tried installing Heroku Add-ons but that is not what I am looking for.

How can I create custom accounts for sending and receiving emails with a custom account (client@site.com) 
I don't want to send mails via node.js nor PHP.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will only host your HTTP website. You need another provider for emails.
[GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/) will give this to you for example.

By setting up your DNS records properly, you will then be able to tell your domain name to point to Heroku for HTTP requests, and to your emails provider for receiving those messages.

Comment: Is there a free solution for this?
For example, the mail server that provides cPanel in GoDaddy?

Comment: You can use GoDaddy's email servers, yes. You just have to see with them which servers to point the DNS MX records to.